# tabs are on top of my text in my xml

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am using android TabHost in order to add tabs to my android Fragment. My issue is that the tabs are on top of my xml. I would think my fragment xml would automatically start under the tabs?

[image]

My code for these tabs are:

```
public class StatisticsTab extends Fragment {


    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    //Mandatory Constructor
    public StatisticsTab() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("Fragment B"),
                StatisticsPage.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("Fragment C"),
                BreweryStatistics.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentd").setIndicator("Fragment D"),
                StyleStatistics.class, null);


        return rootView;
    }




}
```

and here is the code for one of my fragments in the tab:

```
public class StyleStatistics extends Fragment implements GetStyleStatisticsJSON.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_statistics_layout, container, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        String url = "myURL";

        //async task to get beer taste tag percents
        GetStyleStatisticsJSON task = new GetStyleStatisticsJSON(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(url);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String bID){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new StylePage2();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", bID);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }


}
```

and here is the code for the fragments xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/styleStatsTitle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Your Top Styles"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:padding="5dip"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/yourStyleStatistics"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="@null"

        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_tab.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>





    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: Please post fragment_tabs.xml

Comment: @Aashir I updated my question and posted that xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `TabWidget` in your `fragment_tabs.xml` above `FrameLayout`, example:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: Awesome, will try this out now and see what happens.

Comment: tried it but am getting this error:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4775120371eb041522c8

Comment: I edited my answer and added `FrameLayout` with id `@android:id/tabcontent`. It will be empty as you use realtabcontent for your fragments. Check if that helps.

Comment: worked like a champ! Thanks buddy. I will probably be asking a few more questions on tabs.

Comment: If your interested here is a follow on question I have about tab host:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133245/swipe-scrolling-to-fragments-with-tabhost